# How to "End call" using Calabash Android

Tags: android, ruby, gherkin, calabash

I am newbe in using Calabash.

I have basic android app where I can call or send sms to some people from my contact list.
Then I press call button in my .apk, it's automatically starts calling to person

The problem is - I cant stop this call.
Try to use press and touch steps, but them cant locate element out of given .apk

**Is there some good method to hang up a call?**

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old now but in case it helps anyone, you should be able to hang up using an adb command line call that simulates a keypress on the hang up button.

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
```

For more info on other keyevents see - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html